# Let's Encrypt更新に失敗

Tags: centos, nginx, letsencrypt

**作成して三ヶ月後ぐらいにhttpsエラーになったので、下記コマンドを打ちました**

```
   certbot renew
```

・すると下記エラーが表示されました

```
Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01 challenge.
```

---

**どういう意味ですか？**
・作成出来たのに更新できないのは、なぜ？？
・どこを確認すれば良いですか？

---

**https化したドメインのイメージ**

> a.example.com
>
> b.example.com
>
> c.example.net

---

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx

Comment: Lets’s Encryptで発行した証明書の有効期限は90日なので、「更新」は切れる前に行うべきですし、既に失効していたら作り直す必要があるのではないでしょうか。「エラーになったから」ではなく、証明書の有効期限を確認しましょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

letsencryptではドメインの確認のため、certbotが臨時の公開鍵で署名したファイルをディレクトリー`/.well-known/acme-challenge`に置いて、そこに`ACME Challenge`してきます。もしそのディレクトリーに適正にアクセスできなかければ、そのエラーが発生します。例えば、3つのドメインのどれかを301リダイレクトしていないでしょうか？

そういう場合には、letsencrypt用に`webroot`を別に設定するようにします。`webroot`の場所はどこでもいいですが、403にならないようにしておきます。

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/acme-challenge;
}
```